# Rolling disk in inclined plane and flat plane?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, energy-conservation, friction, work

A disk is rolling (not sliding) in the inclined plane with initial velocity of zero. So there is friction between disk and plane. But when we use the energy conservation rule, we consider as:

```
gained kinetic energy + gained rotational energy = lost potential energy
```

So here is there no work against friction? Can anyone explain?
[image]

My second question is a practical question. If in the first question there is no work done by friction, explain this scenario: rolling a disk in a plane with initial velocity of $V$, but it stops in a short distance. How this is possible to use energy conservation theory?

```
lost kinetic energy + lost rotational energy = ?
```

[image]

But most people say here also that work done by friction is zero and air friction stops the disk.

Can anybody explain the work done by friction thing in depth?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Static as opposed to Kinetic Friction in Rolling Motion](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/67118/)

Answer (score 0):

1st que- as the point in contact of the disk and the plane is not moving, no work is done. and as for the second question; no body is perfectly rigid, therefore due to deformation there is loss in energy. that is why the disk stops.

Answer (score 0):

The friction acts only when the contact point slips relative to ground. You can consider speed of lowest point to be sum of $v$ and $\omega r$ with proper directions.

Friction acts till there is slipping and condition for no slipping is $v=\omega r$ when v is right and $\omega$ is clockwise acc. to diagram

As in first case, the lowest point in always stationary with respect to point on ground where friction acts : no work done by friction

In second, the lowest point $will$ slip and work will be done by friction till condition specified.

Then, if you do not consider any other effects the disc will continue its pure rolling motion. But practically there will be deformation at point of contact, heat loss and air resistance.